# Probability Density function of E = exp(2), with a random variable of zero mean and unit variance

Tags: probability-theory

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around some of the basic concepts surrounding the question:

"Suppose $d$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance. What is the probability density function of $E = d^2$?"

I'm not so much looking for a direct answer, rather some guidance as to the set up of the question.

From my understanding the zero mean and unit variance indicate that the exact value for d is known? Given that the mean is $0$ and the spread of possible values from the mean is 0. Relating this back to $E = d^2$ is where I'm having difficulty. Just don't quite understand the question.

Note: The question provides a hint of:

"Since the sign of $d$ gets lost when it is squared, you can assume $p(d)$ is one-sided, that is, defined for only $d ≥ 0$ and with twice the amplitude of the usual Gaussian."

Any help is greatly appreciated, I haven't really dealt with probability theory prior to now.

Comment: This needs clarification.  Do you mean $E=e^d$?  Or, using the hint as a quide, did you mean $E = d^2$?  Or something else altogether?

Comment: Also, I think you misunderstand the standard normal distribution. Mean $0$ and Standard Deviation $1$ is just the normal distribution in its usual form.  It does not work out to a single possible value.  Now if the Variance were $0$, then you;d have a all the probability concentrated at $0$.

Comment: bugger.... just found out that the textbook had a misprint for this question. It is supposed to be E = d^2. ugh. will delete the question. Though regarding the other comment, i think i misunderstood unit variance as being another way of saying the variance... i.e. zero mean and variance... to clarify... unit variation means variance = 1?

Comment: Got it.  I'll edit it for you.  The hint pretty well tells you the answer now, yes?

Comment: Yes.  I assume that "unit variance" means variance 1.  Granted, it's an odd way to phrase it.

Comment: righto, i understand the idea that if we ignore the negative values we'd have to double p(d), since the total area under the curve = 1, but a little iffy on the idea that the distribution shape doesn't change when d is squared. i.e. would we have the same p(d) if we had E = |d|? To me this would also have d defined for d>= 0.